# top down game - checking, drawing enemy's line of sight area with obstacles

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, math, graphics

Examples of what i'm going to need:
[image]
[image]

I'm using cocos2d to draw a CCTMXTiledMap, on those tiles i'll have to draw the LOS triangle.

How would i test if the player is within that triangle, taking obstacles into account?
How would i draw the line of sight area like in the examples above?

BTW, i wasn't sure if this should have been posted here or on gamedev, don't be mad.

Comment: Try this sister site: gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is your question cocos2d specific or do you want an algorithm?

Comment: You might indeed have better luck posting this on gamedev. I have no doubt that it's considered a "solved problem" in games; it's closely related to Computational Geometry's ["Art Gallery Problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem). I'd also suggest the [algorithm] tag here instead of [iphone], since this question isn't specific to that device.

Comment: @Josh Caswell good point, i've switched the tag. The reason i'm leaving the cocos2d tag thought is because i need some help with getting the area drawn on screen :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to look at point-in-polygon algorithms such as the ray casting algorithm described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

You can break up the triangle to account for obstacles, or just make a more complex polygon. You should be able to find an implementation to suit your needs online.

You may also want to take a look at [this article](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html) for some inspiration. You can maintain a tree like structure, a root triangle (or fulcrum) that can be used to determine whether a point is in general line of sight, with the children (triangles) taking obstacles into account. That way you can quickly eliminate more complex checks.

In the image below the dark blue dots are quickly eliminated from further checking as they do not fall within the root viewing triangle.

[image]